# "Demand that the dismissed employee be reinstated" or "demand is that the dismissed employee to be reinstated"

Tags: tenses

Which one is correct?

> The demand of the workers' union that the dismissed employee **be**
>   reinstated, has been accepted by the management.

or

> The demand of the workers' union **is** that the dismissed employee
>   **to be** reinstated, has been accepted by the management.

Comment: Depends if it is being read by the workers or management.

Comment: read by the workers and accepted by management

Answer (score 5):

The second sentence is ungrammatical. It contains a dependent clause with a post-modified subject (the dismissed employee *TO BE reinstated*) but no predicate.

Removing the post-modification results in:

> The demand of the workers' union is that the dismissed employee, has been 
>   accepted by the management

which is clearly incorrect.

The first sentence is correct and contains the subjunctive *be*. However, the simple subject (*demand*) should not be separated from its simple predicate (*has been accepted*) by the comma. This is better omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd one is wrong. The 'is' creates a run-on sentence & distracts from the real meaning of the sentence that the demand was accepted. The point of the sentence can be distilled to say, "The demand was accepted." All of the rest is additional detail embellishing that. The demand was made by the workers' union. The demand was for a reinstatement of an employee who was dismissed. The management accepted the demand.
Really for clarity this sentence is lacking by trying to rely on subordinate phrasing -- a parenthetical ("that the dismissed employee be reinstated") and a prepositional clause ("by the management.") Really I think the parenthetical phrase is the problem and if I were to keep it, I would put a comma before it also to make it look more parenthetical. Or make it a compound sentence like: "The workers' union demanded the reinstatement of the dismissed employee and management has acquiesced to it." Accepting a demand could mean only hearing it & discussing it -- allowing it on the negotiation table without giving into the demand. Or it could be worded: "The demand of the workers' union FOR the dismissed employee TO BE reinstated, has been accepted by the management." but I would prefer, "The workers' union's demand to reinstate the dismissed employee was accepted by management."